# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') - sklearn cosine similarity

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I have two DataFrames that I am trying to run [`numpy cosine_similarity`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#cosine-similarity) on. Here are the two DataFrames when I print them.

Output of `df.info()`:

[image: df.info() output]

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'col1': [2000], 
                    'col2': [1994], 
                    'col3': [2007], 
                    'col4': [88],
                    'col5': [44]
                   })


df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                    'col1': [667, 2207, 1940, 819], 
                    'col2': [1962, 1926, 1988, 1985], 
                    'col3': [2014, 2017, 2017, 2014], 
                    'col4': [80, 92, 89, 86],
                    'col5': [45, 0, 48, 0]
                   })


from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

cos_arr = cosine_similarity(df1.values, df2.values)
```

There are no `NaNs` or `Infs` in the Data. So, I am wondering where the error is coming from.

```
File "/Users/calc.py", line 270, in calc_rent
    cos_arr = cosine_similarity(df1.values, df2.values)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 1179, in cosine_similarity
    X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X, Y)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 72, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/pairwise.py", line 145, in check_pairwise_arrays
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse, dtype=dtype,



ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')
```

Comment: Aren't the two arguments of `cosine_similarity` supposed to be the same shape? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity Are you trying to calculate cosine similarity for each row of df2?

Comment: Not exactly, the columns need to be same, not the number of rows. I have been running `cosine_similarity` on the two data frames that are not the same shape. The issue is with datatype, I think.

Comment: When I ran the sample code you've give, `cos_arr` looks fine: `array([[0.9277767 , 0.99833204, 0.99988486, 0.94487102]])`. is there something you're leaving out?

Comment: @philosofool The dataframe is sample (can't include all data). It's not exactly reproducible.

Comment: @kms , if we can't reproduce your problem, we can't help you

Comment: @kms - can you post a screenshot (or code) containing the output of df.info() on your actual data for both dataframes? Otherwise, it's hard to help without knowing what's in the data.

Comment: @TCArlen I have included the output of `df.info()` in the question.

Comment: @kms you must have included the output of `df.info` NOT `df.info()`. You need the parentheses so we can see what the summary data is. Please update the post to include this.

Comment: @TCArlen Post has been updated to include `df.info()`